# Change directory Vs. full path

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I was wondering what the best practices are on working with paths in the following scenario: 
I can either choose to change the current directory to the desired folder and then generate a file using only the file name, or just use the full path directly.

Here is the code where I set the current directory `os.chdir()`:

```
a=time.clock()
import os
for year in range(start,end):
    os.chdir("C:/CO2/%s" % year)
    with open("Table.csv",'r') as file:
        content=file.read()
b=time.clock()
b-a
Out[55]: 0.002037443263361638
```

And that is slower than when using the full path directly:

```
a=time.clock()
for year in range(start,end):
    with open("C:/CO2/%s/Table.csv" % year,'r') as file:
        content=file.read()
b=time.clock()
b-a

Out[56]: 0.0014569102613677387
```

I still doubt though whether using the full path is good practice. Are both the methods cross platform? Should I be using `os.path` instead of %s?

Comment: I doubt that putting the absolute part `C:/CO2/` in your code is a good idea. The rest doesn't matter.

Comment: I would use os.path.join

Comment: @LutzHorn, sometimes I get a path with inconsistent slash separators such as C:/CD2\\2001
Would it probably be better to just chdir to C:/CD2 and then work on the file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you mean this os.chdir(os.path.join("C:","CD2")) ?

Answer (score 2):

What's the use case for the code in question? Is it a script invoked on the command line by a user? If so, I would usually take the path as a command-line argument (`sys.argv`), as a command-line option (`argparse`), or using some sort of configuration file.

Or is the file path part of a more general-purpose module? In that case, I might think about wrapping the path and related code in a class (`class FooBar`). Users of the module could pass in the needed file path information when instantiating a `FooBar`. If users tended to use the same path over and over, I would again lean toward a strategy based on a configuration file.

Either way, **the file path would be separate from the code** -- at least for real software projects.

If we're talking about a one-off script with very few users and almost zero likelihood of future evolution or code re-use, it does not matter too much what you do.

Answer (score 1):

As @lutz-horn said, hardcoded path isn't good idea for any code, except single-run scripts.

Talking about design, choose the methods that seem to be more explicit and simple for further development, don't optimize your code until run time becomes an issue.

In particular case, I'd prefer second way. No need to `chdir` until you're writing consistent files. You should use explicit `chdir` in case you're writing many files with different name schemas.